# How to know the width of a table td after it has been created and populated using React/Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to retrieve the width from a table after this has been created and populated with data.

I want to see how many words I can fit into the table data cell and then create a "show more"/"show less" button. But for this, I need to know the width of the column...

I'm using an external library so I can't really manipulate the table, except providing the rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution

```
const tableDataCell = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];

    if (tableDataCell) {
        console.log(tableDataCell.clientWidth)
    }
```